# ipsec on linux,a simple and fast question

Tags: ipsec

Is my first VPN, for testing

this is my simple network scheme

```
LAN1(private 10.10.0.0/24) --->VPN-----internet---<VPN---<LAN2(private 10.20.0.0/24)
```

on `/etc/ipsec.conf` i use..

```
...
        left=ippublicserver1
        leftid=fqdnserverA
        leftsubnet=10.10.0.0/24
        right=ippublicserver2
        rightsubnet=10.20.0.0/24
....
```

My question is really simple..,on the serverB I have to use

1. An IDENTICAL `ipsec.conf`
2. A Different `ipsec.conf` where rigthsubnet become leftsubnet?

I think..B, is correct?

Comment: mostly correct. VPNs are a complex matter, and I would advise investigating it more before using them in production.

Comment: Is not production,virtual machines for testing and improve knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct:** A Different ipsec.conf where rigthsubnet become leftsubnet

The statement *leftsubnet* is every a server at where you write a config, e.g you lan

In this example:

**LAN1 Gateway,** leftsubnet is 10.10.0.0/24 and rightsubnet is 10.20.0.0/24

**LAN2 Gateway,** leftsubnet is 10.20.0.0/24 and rightsubnet is 10.10.0.0/24

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SAME `ipsec.conf` on both servers. Quoting from https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection (my emphasis),

> Connection descriptions are defined in terms of a left endpoint and a right endpoint. [...] For every
>   connection description **an attempt is made to figure out whether the local endpoint should act as the left or
>   the right endpoint**. This is done by matching the IP addresses defined for both endpoints with the
>   IP addresses assigned to local network interfaces [...]

What this means is that although there is a nominal convention that left = local, it doesn't actually matter.